# direct_mail_subscription throws error under php 7

Tags: typo3

TYPO3 7.6.14, php 7.0.12 throws: Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20170302191205e900dbd4 after sending the form to the server. The user is made but the email is not sent. This happens with both versions, from TER and from git.

When changing to php 5.6 the extension works as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is caused by a PHP 7 deprecation warning.

I've just encountered this problem a couple of days ago and fixed it:
https://github.com/kartolo/direct_mail_subscription/issues/20

There is no new release yet, but you can use my patch.
Feel free to leave a comment in the GitHub issue if the patch works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a first solution, disable the content exception handler with

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#contentobjectexceptionhandler) for some more explanations.

By guessing there is an issue with overriding methods and changing there declarations. Report it to the author, maybe including a patch.